# Populating Web Table with MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I've been through a ton of answers on this site, but the changes I've made to my code based on their recommendations still hasn't brought me to a solution.

Trying to use PHP to call a MySQL database in order to populate this table with info for an office-internal web page. This is the code as I have it now:

```
<?php
    require_once 'login.php';
    $db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

    if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db($db_database, $db_server)
        or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

    $query = "Select * FROM tablename";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    ?>
                        <table class="mainTable TableTools table-hover table-condensed table-small dataTable sortable" id="DataTables_Table_0" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_0_info">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Blade Name:activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 82px;">
                                <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">
                                    Blade Name
                                    <span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Alias:activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 82px;">
                                <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">
                                    Alias
                                    <span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Chassis Name:activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 82px;">
                                <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">
                                    Chassis Name
                                    <span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="PDU:activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 82px;">
                                <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">
                                    PDU
                                    <span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Circuit Info:activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 82px;">
                                <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">
                                    Circuit Info
                                    <span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Description:activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 82px;">
                                <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">
                                    Description
                                    <span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Degraded:activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 82px;">
                                <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">
                                    Degraded
                                    <span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Blade Type:activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 82px;">
                                <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">
                                    Blade Type
                                    <span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Instance:activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 82px;">
                                <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">
                                    Instance
                                    <span class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
       <?php
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[ServerName] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[EncolsureName] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[Rackname] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[Health_State] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

       ?>
```

The table stuff is a little messy because I'm adapting it from a page that already exists, so I'm trying to model its look. Can any of you guys point out where I'm going wrong? I know HTML, but I'm very inexperienced with PHP, so I feel like I'm missing something that's just staring me in the face.

EDIT: Sorry, first time actually posting on SE (if you couldn't tell) and I've been beating my head against this for a while, so I blanked. The issue is that the page displays the table header, but nothing else.

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is that you're having.

Comment: What is your problem?? Any Error! and yes just a quick suggestion use $row['ServerName'] instead of $row[ServerName]

Comment: Why do you have all those classes in your original code? If you're using DataTables then it will automatically add those for you when the page loads.

Comment: You're treating your rows as [**constants**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) `$row[ServerName]` etc. - Use quotes `$row['ServerName']` etc. - Having [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) on, would've triggered that error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're copying a table that used the dataTables jQuery plugin. You don't need to hardcode in all those classes, the plugin does it for you.

If you want your table to be like theirs, look into [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and, particularly, [dataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) and read the documentation.

It should be something like this (after linking the prerequisite files):

```
<table id="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>header1</th>
            <th>header2</th>
            <!-- etc -->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>content1</td>
            <td>content2</td>
            <!-- etc -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>content1</td>
            <td>content2</td>
            <!-- etc -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#mytable').dataTable();
    });
</script>
```